# Ecryptfs problem with rsync

Tags: rsync, ecryptfs

I use `rsync` to sync my files between my home laptop and my office desktop, with the `-Cauvb --delete` options.

Recently, on my laptop, I encrypted my home directory with `ecryptfs`, which lives on an `ext4` partition, while in the office I use plain `ext4`. The problem is that each time my ecryptfs home gets mounted, the *access time* of all my directories is changed to the time of the mount operation. This messes up my synchronization with `rsync`, because it believes that it needs to synchronize all the directories.

(Note: this holds only for the directories and all the subdirectories, but not to the files in them – apparently, the -u option looks for the *modification time* when it comes to files, but the *access time* for directories? All this is not clear from the `rsync` manpages.)

So I get a lot of output (my directory tree is rather large and complex), and I cannot see what files actually get synchronized. This is a trouble for me, since because of the `--delete` option, I want to see which files get deleted and which ones get overwritten. (Actually, I always run a `--dry-run` before the actual synchronization, but this is useless when the output contains my full directory tree.)

I think that the problem could be solved in two ways:

1. Either the directory access times should not be modified when my `ecryptfs` is mounted,
2. or `rsync` should be instructed to take the *modification time* for directories, as it apparently does for files.

I couldn’t find out how to achieve either. I would prefer the 1st solution as more logical, since from the user point of view, the directories are not accessed just because the `ecryptfs` is mounted.